# How to get the intersection of two jquery objects

Tags: jquery

I have a number of elements with the following markup:

```
<div id="div1" data-category="mycategory" data-feature="myfeature"></div>
<div id="div2" data-category="anothercategory" data-feature="myfeature"></div>
<div id="div3" data-category="mycategory" data-feature="myfeature"></div>
<div id="div4" data-category="mycategory" data-feature="anotherfeature"></div>
```

And two jQuery selectors that reference these:

```
$cats = $('div[data-category="mycategory"]');
$features = $('div[data-features="myfeature"]');
```

How do I merge these two *selectors* into one where BOTH references are true? I want to end up with a selector that only contains div's 1 and 3 but using the already existing $cats and $features - not build another selector based on markup

Comment: My apologies @Jason P i misread OP markup...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Union:

```
$('div[data-category="mycategory"], div[data-features="myfeature"]')...
```

This will get all divs where **either** the `[data-category]` attribute is `mycategory` **or** the `[data-features]` attribute is `myfeature`.

This can be done with multiple selectors as [`$one.add($two)`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

### Intersection:

```
$('div[data-category="mycategory"][data-features="myfeature"]')...
```

This will get all divs where **both** the `[data-category]` attribute is `mycategory` **and** the `[data-features]` attribute is `myfeature`.

This can be done with multiple selectors as [`$one.filter($two)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Sorry but I guess my question was misleading and I've updated it.  What I really want is to use the two existing selectors to arrive at a 3rd which is the intersection of both, rather than create a new one based on the markup.

Comment: damn is it really that simple?! I was looking at the filter method but it seemed so complex to arrive at the result I wanted... I must try this... Works perfectly :) Thank you!

Comment: A model answer for its (1) symmetry between union and intersection, (2) answers for both `$('selectors')` and `$objects`, (3) meticulous formatting, punctuation, and conventions.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.fn.intersect=function(jq){
  return $(this).filter(jq);
}
```

Then :

```
$cats.intersect($features);
```